# Use "Login destination" to redirect the user to a page of Views

Tags: views, users

**Hi everyone.**

I have a **type Article page**, whose alias is: /primaria/docentes/kit.

I have a **type Views page**, whose alias is: /primaria/docentes/kit.

When a user log, whose role is "primaria", I want to redirect it to the view: /primaria/docentes/kit, not the article: /primaria/docentes/kit. (To do this, I use the [Login destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module).

If we write /primaria/docentes/kit in the browser, the page type "article" is always displayed. The view is never displayed. Drupal has a preference for display pages of content types, instead of pages made with Views.

How to redirect the user to view?

In the module "Login destination" add a rule, and use *Page returned by this PHP code (experts only)*. I use this code:

```
$views_page = views_get_view('kit_docente', $reset=FALSE);
if (is_object($views_page)) {
  foreach ($views_page as $a => $b) {
    if($a == "display") {
      foreach ($b as $c => $d) {
        if ($c == "kit_docente_primaria") {
          foreach ($d as $e => $f) {
            if ($e == "display_options") {
              foreach ($f as $g => $h) {
                if ($g == "path") {
                  return $h;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code works fine. But redirects the user to the article. No view of views.

Thanks in advance. :(

Comment: why is your article url and view url identical? urls are suppose to be unique. I would create a view block instead of view page and put the view block in the article page.

Comment: They are identical for this. I have 2 different contents: **C-1** and **C-2**. Both have the same URL. If the visitor is an _anonymous user_, then I want that URL displays the contents C-1. If the visitor is an _authenticated user_, I want that URL displays the contents C-2. That is all!